# Multible tables in Excel. Problems when adding new rows

Tags: excel

I a spreadsheet I have 12 tables. They are all build as copies of the first one.

In the table I have a lot of formulas,e.g.

```
 =Round([@[Købspris pr stk]]/(100-[@[DG pr stk]])*100;2)
```

When I insert new rows, by `Ctrl +` or others, The new row should hold a copy of the actual row.

Instead the formula in the new row is:

```
=Round(KalkulationDKK1[@[Købspris pr stk]]/(100-KalkulationDKK1[@[DG pr stk]])*100;2)
```

"KalkulationDKK1" is the table name of the original table.

I can't see why, and I can't fix it.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

When you are using tables, Excel will default to structured references instead of relative references. Here are some suggestions to what you can do:

- Edit the formulas after copying them, and manually remove the table name.
- Edit the formulas to use relative references instead of structured references before copying them.
- Combine all 12 tables into 1 table, using an extra column to distinguish between them
- Do not use tables. All references will be relative and copy behaves as you would expect.